# How do I display a array of objects on a bootstrap media component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a ajax call that take in an array[30] of object with details inside like title etc. What I want to do is display these objects on a media list and each time the user put a new string into a input bar the  media list will be updated and will return the reults. below is the html I use to retrieve the data and create a GET request dynamically.

```
<div class="container">
      <div style="background: rgba(60, 255, 60, 0.2);" class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Meal Manager</h1>
        <p class="lead">A simple recipe app that provides ingerdiants fast.</p>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" value="chicken" id="sbar" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="button" title="Search Database">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn" title="Sort by reviews" >
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn" title="Sort by trending" >
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
        </div>
          <table id="location" class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>Step</th>
            <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery" aria-hidden="true"></span>  Ingredients</th>
        </tr>
       </table>
```

Now below Is where I will be making the contents of the table then returning them to the html page. The ajax returns the correct data to the callback fucntion but how to I display these on a media component? http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/media-object/

```
function callback(response) {
    // Here you can do what ever you want with the response object.
    console.log(response[responseCnt].title);
    console.log(response[responseCnt+1].title);
    console.log(response[responseCnt+2].title);
    console.log(response[responseCnt+3].title);
    console.log(response[responseCnt+4].title);
}

$(document).ready(function(){

   $("button").click(function(){

     var word = document.getElementById("sbar").value;
 $.ajax({
    url: 'https://community-food2fork.p.mashape.com/search?key=0ee5a01caf7f7c3512b54978628f1a4e&page=4&q=' + word, // The URL to the API. You can get this in the API page of the API you intend to consume
    type: 'GET', // The HTTP Method, can be GET POST PUT DELETE etc
    data: {}, // Additional parameters here
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) { search = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.recipes));
                             callback(search);
                           },
    error: function(err) { alert(err); },
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mashape-Authorization", "gH609jhjxAmshYY4KnIDmad2zgXGp194YDUjsnHCTiPdd7m2Qg"); // Enter here your Mashape key
    }
});
    });


});
```

Now heres what I want to do, I need to fill the html below with the details oh the returned json object inside callback, how to I do this?

```
<div class="media" id="sresults">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="..." >
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```